# Get MySQL table columns in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to find Mysql columns of a table in PHP.

This is my code but it does not work as expected:

```html
while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($query3))
{
    foreach($row3 as $column => $data)
 {
     echo'<td>'.$column.'</td>';
 }
}
```

The table columns in the database are `ID`, `User` and `Pass`.

But the output is 0 ID 1 User 2 Pass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
```

use this.

Answer (score 4):

You can use DESCRIBE:

```
DESCRIBE my_table;
```

Or in newer versions you can use INFORMATION_SCHEMA:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_database' AND TABLE_NAME = 'my_table';
```

Or you can use SHOW COLUMNS:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM my_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Change mysql_fetch_array($query) to mysql_fetch_assoc($query).**

It will give array of column name as a key and column's value as value.